# Scrape eBay Sold Items Using Selenium Returns []

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I have almost no webscraping experience, and wasn't able to solve this using BeautifulSoup, so I'm trying selenium (installed it today). I'm trying to scrape sold items on eBay. I'm trying to scrape:

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=oakley+sunglasses&_sacat=0&Brand=Oakley&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_ipg=200&_oaa=1&_fsrp=1&_dcat=79720

Here is my code where I load in html code and convert to selenium html:

```
    ebay_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=oakley+sunglasses&_sacat=0&Brand=Oakley&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_ipg=200&_oaa=1&_fsrp=1&_dcat=79720'

    html = requests.get(ebay_url)
    #print(html.text)

    driver = wd.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/mburley/Downloads/chromedriver')
    driver.get(ebay_url)
```

Which correctly opens a new chrome session at the correct url. I'm working on getting the titles, prices, and date sold and then loading it into a csv file. Here is the code I have for those:

```
    # Find all div tags and set equal to main_data
    all_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("s-item__info clearfix")[1:]
    #print(main_data)

    # Loop over main_data to extract div classes for title, price, and date
    for item in all_items:
    date = item.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'POSITIVE']").text.strip()
    title = item.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[contains(@class, 's-item__title s-item__title--has-tags']").text.strip()
    price = item.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 's-item__price']").text.strip()

    print('title:', title)
    print('price:', price)
    print('date:', date)
    print('---')
    data.append( [title, price, date] )
```

Which just returns []. I think ebay may be blocking my IP, but the html code loads in and looks correct. Hopefully someone can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to scrape the details. also you can use pandas to store data in csv file.

**Code :**

```
ebay_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=oakley+sunglasses&_sacat=0&Brand=Oakley&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_ipg=200&_oaa=1&_fsrp=1&_dcat=79720'

html = requests.get(ebay_url)
# print(html.text)

driver = wd.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/mburley/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(ebay_url)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
sold_date = []
title = []
price = []
i = 1
for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'title--tagblock')]/span[@class='POSITIVE']"):
    sold_date.append(item.text)
    title.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//div[contains(@class,'title--tagblock')]/span[@class='POSITIVE']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'tag')]/following-sibling::a/h3)[{i}]").text)
    price.append(item.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//div[contains(@class,'title--tagblock')]/span[@class='POSITIVE']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'tag')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'details')]/descendant::span[@class='POSITIVE'])[{i}]").text)
    i = i + 1

print(sold_date)
print(title)
print(price)

data = {
         'Sold_date': sold_date,
         'title': title,
         'price': price
        }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv('out.csv', index = 0)
```

**Imports :**

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you! However, I did run into the error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[contains(@class,'title--tagblock')]/span[@class='POSITIVE']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'tag')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'details')]/descendant::span[@class='POSITIVE'])[177]"}
(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)

Comment: Does this mean a post did not have this information? Does the code you gave need a try/except? Again, thanks!

Comment: you can wrap inside try-except as well. and I do see it's failing for 177 element, for that either you should use any known API of ebay, or with selenium you will have to scroll down for each and every element.

Comment: It's close. The server keeps prompting me for captchas, which seems to throw the scraper off, as then it only prints roughly 20 items. Also, I think I'll just wrap that line in a try/except and have it print null.

Comment: these are all off-topic question from this thread. you have the option to create new post for them.

Comment: Okay back on topic, I see you create wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20), but don't actually see wait used anywhere inside the loop like I think you'd want it to. Why is that?

Comment: Well initially I thought, I will fetch elements one by one with find_element, not with find_elements. Since I had setup implicit wait. You can remove the explicit wait, that ain't used anywhere.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is when you ran this did you get all 200 results? I can't get this to save my life...

Comment: No, 192 items, there's a drop down as well to filter 24 items per page.

Comment: I posted a new thread on the pagination of the same page, do you mind taking a look @cruisepandey?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use `Selenium` for eBay scraping, as the data is not rendered by JavaScript thus can be extracted from plain HTML. It is enough to use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library.

Keep in mind that problems with site parsing may arise when you try to request a site multiple times. eBay may consider that this is a bot that sends a request (not a real user).

To avoid this, one of the ways is to send `headers` that contain [user-agent in the request](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#user-agent), then the site will assume that you're a user and display information.

As an [additional step is to rotate those user-agents](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents). The ideal scenario is to use [proxies](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#proxies) in combo with rotated user-agents (besides CAPTCHA solver)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
    
params = {
    '_nkw': 'oakley+sunglasses',      # search query  
    'LH_Sold': '1',                   # shows sold items
    '_pgn': 1                         # page number
}

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    print("-" * 10)
    
    for products in soup.select(".s-item__info"):
        title = products.select_one(".s-item__title span").text
        price = products.select_one(".s-item__price").text
        link = products.select_one(".s-item__link")["href"]
        
        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Example output

```json
Extracting page: 1
----------
[
  {
    "title": "Shop on eBay",
    "price": "$20.00",
    "link": "https://ebay.com/itm/123456?hash=item28caef0a3a:g:E3kAAOSwlGJiMikD&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAsJoWXGf0hxNZspTmhb8%2FTJCCurAWCHuXJ2Xi3S9cwXL6BX04zSEiVaDMCvsUbApftgXEAHGJU1ZGugZO%2FnW1U7Gb6vgoL%2BmXlqCbLkwoZfF3AUAK8YvJ5B4%2BnhFA7ID4dxpYs4jjExEnN5SR2g1mQe7QtLkmGt%2FZ%2FbH2W62cXPuKbf550ExbnBPO2QJyZTXYCuw5KVkMdFMDuoB4p3FwJKcSPzez5kyQyVjyiIq6PB2q%7Ctkp%3ABlBMULq7kqyXYA"
  },
  {
    "title": "Oakley X-metal Juliet  Men's Sunglasses",
    "price": "$280.00",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/265930582326?hash=item3deab2a936:g:t8gAAOSwMNhjRUuB&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoH76tlPncyxembf4SBvTKma1pJ4vg6QbKr21OxkL7NXZ5kAr7UvYLl2VoCPRA8KTqOumC%2Bl5RsaIpJgN2o2OlI7vfEclGr5Jc2zyO0JkAZ2Gftd7a4s11rVSnktOieITkfiM3JLXJM6QNTvokLclO6jnS%2FectMhVc91CSgZQ7rc%2BFGDjXhGyqq8A%2FoEyw4x1Bwl2sP0viGyBAL81D2LfE8E%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8yw1LH9YA"
  },
  {
    "title": " Used Oakley PROBATION Sunglasses Polished Gold/Dark Grey  (OO4041-03)",
    "price": "$120.00",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/334596701765?hash=item4de7847e45:g:d5UAAOSw4YtjTfEE&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoItMbbzfQ74gNUiinmOVnzKlPWE%2Fc54B%2BS1%2BrZpy6vm5lB%2Bhvm5H43UFR0zeCU0Up6sPU2Wl6O6WR0x9FPv5Y1wYKTeUbpct5vFKu8OKFBLRT7Umt0yxmtLLMWaVlgKf7StwtK6lQ961Y33rf3YuQyp7MG7H%2Fa9fwSflpbJnE4A9rLqvf3hccR9tlWzKLMj9ZKbGxWT17%2BjyUp19XIvX2ZI%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8yw1LH9YA"
  },
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It`s a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code that paginates through all pages:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
import os, json

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),      # serpapi api key    
    "engine": "ebay",                     # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",            # ebay domain
    "_nkw": "oakley+sunglasses",          # search query
    "_pgn": 1,                             # page number           
    "LH_Sold": "1"                        # shows sold items
}

search = EbaySearch(params)        # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        link = organic_result.get("link")
        price = organic_result.get("price")

        data.append({
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })
                    
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
        params['_pgn'] += 1

    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$68.96",
      "extracted": 68.96
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/125360598217?epid=20030526224&hash=item1d3012ecc9:g:478AAOSwCt5iqgG5&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4Ls3N%2FEH5OR6w3uoTlsxUlEsl0J%2B1aYmOoV6qsUxRO1d1w3twg6LrBbUl%2FCrSTxNOjnDgIh8DSI67n%2BJe%2F8c3GMUrIFpJ5lofIRdEmchFDmsd2I3tnbJEqZjIkWX6wXMnNbPiBEM8%2FML4ljppkSl4yfUZSV%2BYXTffSlCItT%2B7ZhM1fDttRxq5MffSRBAhuaG0tA7Dh69ZPxV8%2Bu1HuM0jDQjjC4g17I3Bjg6J3daC4ZuK%2FNNFlCLHv97w2fW8tMaPl8vANMw8OUJa5z2Eclh99WUBvAyAuy10uEtB3NDwiMV%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR5DKgLD9YA"
  },
  {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$62.95",
      "extracted": 62.95
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/125368283608?epid=1567457519&hash=item1d308831d8:g:rnsAAOSw7PJiqMQz&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4AwZhKJZfTqrG8VskZL8rtfsuNtZrMdWYpndpFs%2FhfrIOV%2FAjLuzNzaMNIvTa%2B6QUTdkOwTLRun8n43cZizqtOulsoBLQIwy3wf19N0sHxGF5HaIDOBeW%2B2sobRnzGdX%2Fsmgz1PRiKFZi%2BUxaLQpWCoGBf9n8mjcsFXi3esxbmAZ8kenO%2BARbRBzA2Honzaleb2tyH5Tf8%2Bs%2Fm5goqbon%2FcEsR0URO7BROkBUUjDCdDH6fFi99m6anNMMC3yTBpzypaFWio0u2qu5TgjABUfO1wzxb4ofA56BNKjoxttb7E%2F%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR5DKgLD9YA"
  },
  # ...
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.